# vim indention not preserving spacing

Tags: vim, tabs, indentation, space

Below is example text I put in vim, only spaces used no tabs.

```
dog;
dogcat
  dogcatmoose
box
  box car
woop
  woopadoop
```

Lets say I highlight all code, and use indention `>` what happens is the following:

```
    dog;
    dogcat
    dogcatmoose
    box
    box car
    woop
    woopadoop
```

Original spacing is not preserved. I dont want that, I want spacing to be preserved so it looks like this:

```
  dog;
  dogcat
    dogcatmoose
  box
    box car
  woop
    woopadoop
```

I tested with tabs instead of spaces. When using tabs, indention preserves the tabs.
Here is my vimrc. IS there some value in here causing this problem? Is there a value I can add to fix the problem?

```
set number
set nowrap
set linebreak
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set shiftround
set expandtab
set title
set mouse=a
set hlsearch
set smarttab
set autoindent
set smartindent
set background=dark
filetype indent on
set filetype=html
set smartindent
set nocompatible
filetype off
set nobackup noswapfile
set clipboard=unnamed
let &colorcolumn=join(range(81,999),",")
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=235 guibg=#2c2d27
"Stop vm from indenting on comment out sections starting with "#"
set indentkeys-=0#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to get rid of `set shiftround`.

It seems like `set shiftround` coupled with `set shiftwidth=4` is causing the behaviour. `shiftround` tries to indent the text to multiples of 4 (which is set by `shiftwidth`), while your text is indented with 2 spaces. So when you do `>`, `shiftround` makes all the lines have the same 4-space indent. You can experiment this with the same text but with 4-space indentation; your setting will preserve the indentation.